# Ineffective pre-workouts

Tags: supplements, pre-workout

I have been using a pre-workout for the past 3 years, but I'm not entirely sure why.  I can drink my pre-workout 30-45 minutes before my workout starts and not feel a thing.  No "tingling" that so many people talk about.  No burst of energy and definitely no sustained energy.  I've tried many different brands, even did the much talked about 2 scoops.  Nothing.  My current brand is PreKaged by Kaged Muscle, I like the flavor, but still not feeling a difference.

I do have a high tolerance to a lot of medications; Ambien did absolutely nothing. Hydrocodone just gives me cotton mouth and nothing for pain relief. I can even drink a cup of coffee or a pop and take a nap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pre-workout usually has a diminishing effect.  The first time can make you very jittery due to caffeine and other ingredients but over time you feel less of a jolt.  This is mostly true if you are taking it 3 or more times  a week.   Also worth mentioning, genetics determine how fast your body breaks down caffeine [according to this link](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2016/07/12/for-coffee-drinkers-the-buzz-may-be-in-your-genes/?_r=0).  The link mentions that slow metabolizers have increased heart attack risk when drinking large amounts of coffee.

Answer (score 3):

Using pre-workout for 3 years is way too long.

The "tingling" comes from the Beta-Alanine, if you try standalone 1-1,5gr of Beta-Alanine you will definitely get the "tingling", that doesn't mean i recommend you to do.

Pre-Workouts basically include creatine,beta-alanine,bcaa,caffeine from various stimulants and extracs, might include citruline if it's a "pump"-labeled, arginine, taurine, agmatine, etc. They might work for the first 3-4 times but for the majority of them nothing much more than that. In general they are just waste of money, a mix of cheap ingredients labeled on whatever the selling company wants to promote.

You can use a pre-workout but not for too long time and not every day. Think it as a little weapon for the hard day workout, e.g. leg day.

---

**But.**

If you want a wake up call before your workout drink a single espresso 30-45 minutes before.

If you want an energy pump, a small fresh apple is just enough also 30-45 minutes before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using preworkouts for years too. I tried many brands and there is no magic in that stuff. Now im doing my own preworkout with my way. I like tingling feeling and i put arround 2gr of **beta-alanine**, cold brew coffee that contains 150mg **caffeine**, 5gr of **creatine**, 5 gr of **arginine**, 5 gr of **bcaa**, 5gr of **citrulline** ...etc in my shaker and voila. That's way cheaper compared with ready product and I can manipulate it as I want. But the most important thing about preworkouts, body get used to the stimulants like caffeine so i don't consume coffee in workout days and i do caffeine diet to give body a rest. If you dont mind about taste thats a great method but if you care my favorites are C4 and PRE-JYM as preworkout.

Answer (score 0):

Taking preworkout consistently for 3 years is **way too long**. Taking preworkout consistently for 3 *months* is way too long. You've probably developed a complete tolerance for any sensible amount of caffeine now and will never achieve any stimulation from it. Safe to say after 3 years your body has adapted. You have to cycle off stimulants to (attempt to) reset your tolerance. If I was in your situation, I'd take at least a couple months off any stimulants (besides coffee if you're a drinker) and see how you respond after that. And if a few months go by and when you take it you don't feel any benefits, stay off it for another while.